# Fourier Transform of a periodic function and LTI transfer functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, fourier-transform

I am taking a signals and systems class and within it is the idea of taking a Fourier transform of a periodic function.

Can someone explain this and put it on rigorous footing? Clearly such a function doesn't exist, even as a limit. The concept of "distribution" doesn't really apply here either as it is being treated as a function. For example it is being multiplied with a LTI frequency-domain transfer function then inverted to get the output of the system to the periodic input.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform of a $1$-periodic function $f(t)$ is the distribution

$$\hat{f}
 (\xi)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(\xi−n)c_n$$ where $c_n= \int_0^1
f(t)e^{−2i\pi nt}dt$ are the Fourier series coefficients.

It is a major difficulty in signal processing : for unifying

- the discrete Fourier transform,
- the Fourier series,
- the discrete-time Fourier transform,
- and the Fourier transform

you need the Fourier transform of distributions.